# Spring Kafka: How to replace retry template with new BackOff and Recoverer of SeekToCurrentErrorHandler?

Tags: spring-kafka

I am currently using a retry template and tried to replace it with the new capabilities that the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler provides (Recoverer and BackOff). However, I do not yet get the exact same behaviour. With the retry template, a delivery was tried 5 times with a back-off. When the retries were exhausted, an error was logged. The SeekToCurrentErrrorHandler subsequently seeked back and than the process started all over again, starting with 5 new retries with backoff.

I now changed this to the following:

```
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(kafkaProperties.getListener().getConcurrency());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory(kafkaProperties, meterRegistry));
    FixedBackOff backOff = new FixedBackOff(3000L, 5);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new LoggingRecoverer(), backOff));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    return factory;
  }

  class LoggingRecoverer implements BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> {
    @Override
    public void accept(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Exception e) {
      MessageKeyAvro key = (MessageKeyAvro) record.key();
      LOGGER.error(
          "Retrying failed after {} attempts. "
              + "Topic: {} Partition: {} Offset: {} "
              + "Root Context ID: {} Aggregate Type: {} Aggregate ID: {} Aggregate Version: {} "
              + "Cause: {}",
          "5",
          record.topic(),
          record.partition(),
          record.offset(),
          key.getRootContextIdentifier(),
          key.getAggregateIdentifier().getType(),
          key.getAggregateIdentifier().getIdentifier(),
          key.getAggregateIdentifier().getVersion(),
          e.getMessage());
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
  }
```

This behaves slightly different. After the 5 retries are exhausted, the LoggingRecoverer is called as expected and logs the error. After returning from the LoggingRecoverer the next retries are not using a backoff anymore. The system retries infinite (which is the desired behaviour) but without backoffs. Is there a way to change this so that after the recoverer is called, the next round behaves as the first one with a reset backoff?

Answer (score 0):

No; you should keep the retry template if that's the behavior you want.

Throwing an exception from the recoverer simply tells the framework that recovery failed so it should redeliver the record; it does not reset the back off.

We could add an option to the recoverer to reset the retry state in that case; open a new feature request issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I opened an new feature request issue on GitHub as suggested.